# php serialize function parsing error

Tags: php, notorm

i have this array

```
$x = array(
    1 => 16,
    2 => 8
);
```

and

```
$y = serialize($x);
```

i'm using [notorm](http://www.notorm.com/) and now this query

```
$db->table()->update(array('config' => $y));
```

the query

```
update table set config = 'a:2:{i:1;i:16;i:2;i:8;}'
```

but in the table

```
a?:{i?;s?:"16";i?;s?:"8";}
```

now the question is what's happend to the serialize

Comment: Are you using a "strange" charset?

Comment: why do you think its serialize() function?

Comment: What does `var_dump($y)` display?

Comment: var_dump($y) display the right serialize and the echo query too

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that `serialize` can perfectly handle anything you put in it. However, this could very well be a display issue, or perhaps the data in the database isn't stored as latin1 or UTF-8.

Comment: I just noticed that what's in the table cannot ever be written by the query you mentioned.

Comment: when i echo the query and execute it directly in the phpmyadmin its working

Comment: Every tried to use something else than notORM, to verify that this is not its fault? Like "pure" use of mysql_ functions

Comment: @Sn0opy its worked with the mysql_

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your database the field that holds the data is set to a character encoding of either `utf8_general_ci` (preferred) or `latin1_general_ci`

Comment: i use the same every thing in another table and every thing is ok